# Why rebuild the bat signal in The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, batman

At the end of *The Dark Knight Rises* we see Jim Gordon run his hand across a new bat signal, but as far as he knows Batman is dead and no more. So what was the purpose in building a new bat signal? Whilst it was implied that Robin would become Batman, there was no way for Gordon to know this, so it makes no sense to build the signal.

Comment: I need to watch that again.  I had the impression that it wasn't Gorden, but Wayne who had the Bat Signal rebuilt.

Comment: @BBlake its right at the end. About when they reveal the batman statue.

Comment: @BBlake is correct, I believe. I just rewatched it, and answered below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, no way to answer without spoilers:)

> This entire section of the film is Bruce/Batman letting those that were closest to him know that he is still alive. You can tell by quite a few cinematic clues that this the case. The music is swelling after the downbeat funeral and will reading scene, it is cut into the other three "proof of life" scenes, and most importantly, it occurs *after* the "escape clause" scene, where we learn that the autopilot worked after all.
> When you examine the actual mechanics of the scene, it becomes even more clear. Jim Gordon is reading reports, double takes at seeing the signal repaired, approaches and lays his hand on the symbol to verify that it is real, and then glances all around as though looking for his friend whom he thought was dead.

The entire section is a callback to *Begins*, where Nolan did the exact same style of reveal when he was showing that Bruce had survived the events of that movie.

As for why? Bruce was sowing the seeds for Robin John Blake to take up his mantle and become the new defender of Gotham.

Comment: As far as Jim Gordon is aware he is dead there is nothing to say his still alive. That Gordon knows of, and it quite clear it is a face of satisfaction. He never double takes a look at it. He must be blind as a bat not to see it when he goes up in the first place. Totally disagree.

Comment: rewatch the movie, it's the only possible interpretation.

Comment: plus... gordon whould have no reason to rebuild it, he has already paid tribute to the Bat in the statue scene, just previous.

Comment: I have watched it 4 times since DVD release and love it. I have also just spent a bit more time researching this myself, and whilst the theory is there that Bruce Wayne did repair it. Many have said that Gordon is not surprised to see it there, and that if he did rebuild it then why did he not use the bat signal to signal that he was back as it would have been more visible, instead of the small fire on the bridge which wouldn't have been visible everywhere.

Comment: There is also the theory that it is there to reinforce the legend of batman. I do now believe this question is only going to get speculations and theories and no solid answer. So thank you for your input.

Comment: remember that your answer is only a theory as well, as there is nothing to say it was Bruce Wayne who rebuild it at all. Your just assuming it was him, it could have been anyone based on what you are saying, there is no evidence at all to say Bruce Wayne rebuilt that. Which brings us back to Why it was rebuilt? So that is probably a better reason why i haven't accepted your answer.

Comment: not get drawn into a comment argument here, but the other three scenes in the proof of life section is Robin subsuming the mantle of the Bat and becoming a replacement for Bruce as the hero Gotham needs (an overarching theme of all 3 movies), the repayment of Alfred (rewarding him for years of service by showing him that he had managed to discharge his duty) and Lucius, who gives you the reason that Bruce survived. Showing Gordon fondling the Bat symbol he made doesn't really fit with that, as up to that point, the entirety of Gotham thinks Batman is dead.

Comment: However, as the note that Bruce leaves for his colleague, Jim Gordon, to let him know that he is actually alive and that he has provided a Batman for Gotham, it totally works and is thematically intact with the rest of section of the movie in which it appears.

Comment: I like the theory I really do and I don't what to get into a comment argument either. But it is only a theory, a good theory but still only a theory. Just like the others. If i could accept multiple theories I would but I can't. I am beginning to like yours more then others though as you are providing more and more to your theory. I have unaccepted the answer and I happy to accept yours as you have provided more to your theory then the others.

Comment: Please note I do still like the other answer a lot

Comment: @Popeye: sure, it’s only a theory. But what more do you want? These are fictional events.

Answer (score 9):

While I agree with **Dylan Yaga**'s answer, he left out one major point that I feel should be addressed: Jim Gordon never rebuilt the Bat Signal. He **did** assume Bruce Wayne died.

Gordon was atop MCU looking over case files, as was his habit, and he saw the new Bat Signal after casually glancing towards it. The look on his face as he examines what he thought was a destroyed Bat Signal is surprise.

**Bruce Wayne rebuilt the Bat Signal** when he returned from The Pit, before revealing himself. We are not told how long he is in Gotham beforehand, which allowed him to set up leaving the bookbag that allowed John "Robin" Blake to access the Batcave, and time to rebuild the Bat Signal. He was letting Gordon know that Batman would return to protect the city.

Comment: Although it could be an interpretation, and I really like it, I don't think it's correct. The look at his faces is not surprise at all, but *satisfaction*. Satisfaction for having a symbol, in which he believes, one which had been persecuted and hated, restored, as it has always deserved.

Comment: @Thecafremo I agree I don't believe this is correct ever. Good answer though, I don't believe I can accept it. There is nothing to suggest that Bruce Wayne had anything to do with the rebuild. I would also agree that it is satisfaction on his face, because he must have seen it when he went up there so the surprise would have already been and gone.

Comment: people who are satisfied don't swing their head around in every direction checking for whom ever was up on the roof repairing a bat signal.

Comment: @sarge_smith agreed but people who are surprised don't sit with it without noticing for however long. So like I have already said "I do now believe this question is only going to get speculations and theories and no solid answer." so i am done I have made my mind up based on the answer I feel more towards. I wasn't satisfied with your answer so that's it.

Comment: How do you know that wasn't the first time he was atop the MCU after Batman's "death"? If we're gonna be dogmatic about "he would have noticed it before," then where's the evidence he was up there before?

Answer (score 1):

The film's [official movie novelisation](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Knight-Rises-Official-Movie-Novelization/dp/1781161062) is pretty clear on the sequence of events. In short, Wayne arranged for Blake to take over as Batman (by giving him directions to the Batcave) and for Jim Gordon to be made aware that someone had taken the place of the original Batman (by installing a new bat-signal).

> *Gordon banged the files against the air duct to straighten them. His
>   gaze drifted across the familiar rooftop, then came to an abrupt stop.
>   His jaw dropped, and he forgot all about the arrest reports.
>   The shattered searchlight had been repaired. A brand-new bat-symbol,
>   freshly cast in gleaming steel, was mounted atop an unbroken glass
>   lens.*
>
> *Stepping over to it—hesitantly, as if afraid it might vanish—he ran
>   his fingers reverently along the outline of the emblem. Then he stared
>   up at the night sky, looking for a sign. Perhaps he wasn’t on his own
>   after all.*
>
> ---
>
> *Blake left the daylight behind. Descending into stygian blackness, he pulled a flare out of the bag, and then lit it. A bright
>   red flame sparked to life deep inside the cave. The sudden glare awoke
>   a rustling, chittering mass high above his head. He ducked in alarm as
>   thousands of screeching creatures swooped down from their roosts,
>   flying wildly throughout the cavern. Leathery wings flapped all around
>   him, buffeting him, engulfing him in a flurry of…bats.*

---

The [movie script](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dark-Knight-Trilogy-Christopher-Nolan/dp/0571287786) concurs with this version of events. Gordon was unaware of the repaired Bat-signal until he stumbled across it..

> **EXT. MCU – NIGHT 318**
>
> *Gordon bangs his files against the air duct, straightening them. **He stops. Sees something. The searchlight … fixed**. Gordon runs his
>   fingers across a brand new, steel Bat symbol … He looks up into the
>   night …*

Answer (score 0):

A good ending and a sign of hope.  Gordon is happy to see the rebuilt signal and looks to see if his friend is nearby as Batman would alway surprise him.  Gordon is hopeful again...but wasn't that alway Batmans objective...to give people hope.

Answer (score 0):

**Interpretation #1:**

Gordon didn't rebuild the bat signal. Bruce Wayne did.

[Gordon reading when he looks up and is surprised by something.](https://youtu.be/nvtJ_XC2bz8?t=3m31s)

[Later, he is seen approaching the signal, touching it as if to verify it, and then looks around as if he searching for something (someone).](https://youtu.be/nvtJ_XC2bz8?t=4m6s)

It nicely parallels Bruce's other friends' discoveries, particularly what Bruce had left for Robin.

It seems fairly clear to me that this is the correct interpreation.

**Interpretation #2:**

Even if Gordon *had* repaired the bat signal, it's not true that "it makes no sense".

> Bruce: As a man, I'm flesh and blood, I can be ignored, I can be destroyed; but as a *symbol*...as a symbol I can be incorruptible, I can be ***everlasting.***

This theme is repeated throughout all three movies. It's not about Batman being a hero, but the people of Gotham being inspired to become the heroes. The *symbolism* of the silent guardian of Gotham is more powerful than any man.

Gordon would have had very good reason to repair the signal, even if it hadn't been already done.